# Azure Function CORS Policy not settings reponse headers

Tags: azure, cors, azure-functions

I just set a CORS policy for my all operations like this:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cors>
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>http://localhost:3000</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <method>GET</method>
                <method>POST</method>
            </allowed-methods>
        </cors>
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Failed.">
            <openid-config url="https://*/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>ticket-spa</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://*/</issuer>
            </issuers>
        </validate-jwt>
        <set-header name="X-JWT-SUB" exists-action="override">
            <value>@(context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].First().Split(' ')[1].AsJwt()?.Claims["sub"].FirstOrDefault())</value>
        </set-header>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

However the OPTIONS request to https://*.azure-api.net/myFunctions/items?param=1
results in the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Request-Context: appId=*
Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2020 07:22:47 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Which results in the browser not allowing communicating with my API because the CORS headers are missing.

Comment: Have you tried setting the CORS policy through the portal or CLI? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#cors . I mention this because azure functions has weirdness where certain settings that are exposed in portal can't be properly configured from appsettings file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like I had to add a few allowed headers like this:

```
<allowed-headers>
                <header>content-type</header>
                <header>accept</header>
                <header>x-tfs-fedauthredirect</header>
                <header>user-agent</header>
                <header>authorization</header>
            </allowed-headers>
```

Still weird how there's no error indicating why this failed.